# Variable doesn't seem to be taking on new value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, do-while

```
  function reachOne(integer) {
      //deal with errors in input
      var array = [];
      //initialize multiply by putting it equal to 1
      var multiply = 1;
      var count = 0;

      if (integer < 0) {
          document.write('Do it again, Input should be a positive Integer')
      } else if (integer < 10 && integer >= 0) {
          document.write(count);
      } else {

          do {
              for (var i = 0; i < integer.length; i++) {
                  multiply = multiply * integer.charAt(i);
                  //if i try to write document.write(multiply), nothing appears
                  console.log("HELLO");
              }
              count++
          }

          while (multiply >= 10)



      }
      //if I write document.write(multiply) here, the result is 1 and not the product of all the numbers
  }
  reachSingle(254)        

    ----------
```

The code above should take a positive integer, and return the number of times the numbers inside that integer must be multiplied together to get one digit. Example: 254 would give 2:  2*5*4=40  and 4*0 = 0.

Comment: Your `integer` parameter looks like it's supposed to be a number, but that `for` loop is treating it as if it were a string. Thus `integer.length` will be `undefined` so the `for` loop will never happen.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
function reachOne(integer, count) {
 
  if (isNaN(integer) || integer < 1) return 0;
  
 var multiply = 1;
  if (isNaN(count)) count = 1;

  while (integer > 0) {    
    multiply = multiply * (integer % 10);
    integer = Math.floor(integer / 10);
  }
  if (multiply > 9) return reachOne(multiply, ++count);
  return count;
}

console.log(reachOne(254));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert your variable to a string

```
var test = 254;
test = test.toString(); // you need to convert test to a string
var result = 1;
for (var x = 0; test.length > x; x++) {
    result *= test[x]; 
}
```

> result is 40